# Problem converting cURL command to python request

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to convert this cURL command into a python request

```
curl --max-time 300 --data-binary '{"method": "SEED.compare_regions_for_peg", "params": ["fig|218493.5.peg.961", 5000, 20, "pgfam", "representative+reference"], "id": 1}' https://p3.theseed.org/services/compare\_region
```

i've tried using https://curl.trillworks.com/ which returns this code

```
import requests
data = '{"method": "SEED.compare_regions_for_peg", "params": ["fig|218493.5.peg.961", 5000, 20, "pgfam", "representative+reference"], "id": 1}'
response = requests.post('https://p3.theseed.org/services/compare/_region', data=data)
```

but the command `print(response.status_code)` returns 404

Can someone help me identify the problem, as i need to run the same command about 120 000 times with  "fig|218493.5.peg.961" as a variable

Comment: It's unrelated but can you please tell where you found this API endpoint? Is there some place which documents such PATRIC endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with your URL in python request.
In cURL you mentioned URL path `services/compare\_region` but in python `services/compare/_region`

This works fine for me:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> data = '{"method": "SEED.compare_regions_for_peg", "params": ["fig|218493.5.peg.961", 5000, 20, "pgfam", "representative+reference"], "id": 1}'
>>> response = requests.post('https://p3.theseed.org/services/compare_region', data=data)
```